# How to send the req alongside the socket.io socket?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have implemented a socket.io like this:

client:

```
const socket = io.connect(':4000');
socket.emit('trim-movie', data);
```

server:

```
const io = socket(server);
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    socket.on('trim-movie', (data) => trimMovie(data));
});
```

In order to authorize the user in the server I need the request (req) to be send with the socket right?

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

[Try socket io middleware]

> Sending credentials[1]
> The client can send credentials with the auth option:

// plain object

```
const socket = io({
  auth: {
    token: "abc"
  }
});
```

// or with a function

```
const socket = io({
  auth: (cb) => {
    cb({
      token: "abc"
    });
  }
});
```

Those credentials can be accessed in the handshake object on the server-side:

```
io.use((socket, next) => {
  const token = socket.handshake.auth.token;
  // ...
});
```